# how to use Google Maps offline with mapping the location from mysql database?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I want to ask you all something. So, I made an application using Google Maps v3 and map the location from the mysql database. the map which i use is world map. not in a certain location because my database are the IP address location from all over the world. but can I still use and plot the location from mysql database to the Google Maps v3 in offline? What do I need to do? Thank You.

Comment: Using it offline would require you to pre-download all the java script, and all the *tiles* associated with the map. There are a **lot** of tiles in a world map, for all different zoom levels...

Comment: The map images tiles need to be downloaded from google on the fly. Therefore an offline version would not be possible

Comment: @chad, how to download them? Is there any tutorial or articles which has the simple explanation to be done? I'm affraid that i don't understand because I'm newbie.

Comment: @craig1231, is it better to use Google Maps online?

Comment: `"how to download them? Is there any tutorial or articles which has the simple explanation to be done?"`
No
`"is it better to use Google Maps online?"`
Dear God yes.

Comment: Why is it that you want to use this application offline?

Comment: so this is a little impossible to integrated Google Maps v3 in offline @Chad?

Comment: @coyotebush, I just want to anticipating the condition that there is no internet connection. So the user still can use the application in offline.

Comment: Will the user have the MySQL database with them when offline? Or will they load the page then go offline? And does this involve more than a low-detail world map?

Comment: @coyotebush, so i just think about your questions. like your second statement that they load the page then go offline to still use Google Maps v3 to see the location. and involving more than a low-detail world map would be yes.

Comment: Right, so if they need to zoom in to see more detail, I'd have to agree that it's not reasonable or practical to download all the necessary data (map tiles) upfront.

Comment: @coyotebush, it could be done if the user zoom in a location. but how if they zoom for more than one location because the map would always map some location.

Comment: By downloading the tiles you would also be violating the Google Maps API terms of service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments were getting long but I think there has been a consensus:

1. It is impractical to develop an offline application using Google Maps.
2. Even if you could download all the tiles and related files, that would violate the [Google Maps API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).

The direct answer to your question would be "you can't," I and many others in the comments recommend keeping the application online.

Comment: Yes. This has been asked a number of times in the past with the same answer.

Comment: Thank You all for the info. I keep my application online :)